# Ionic4 capacitor android livereload?

Tags: android, livereload, ionic4, capacitor

Is there posibility to run ionic4 app with capacitor on android device with livereload?
I was looking  for answear for a few hours now without a luck. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

If using a recent version of `@ionic/cli`, there is a command now `ionic capacitor run android --livereload --external`

You can do it manually too (if not using ionic CLI or using an old version that doesn't have the mentioned command) by adding the server object to the `capacitor.config.json` file, just use the url of your live reload server

```
"server": {
    "url": "http://192.168.1.33:8100"
}
```

Comment: It looks like the cli automatically adds the "server" key and url value to the config file when I run on livereload. Unfortunately, the url changes every so often, which breaks the security features I have in place, specifically cleartextTrafficPermitted exceptions. If I attempt to manually add the url, the cli will add an "original_url" key and value, which disregards my manual entry. Is there any way to ensure that the livereload server will run on the url I specify?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to livereload without specifying the IP address:

```
ionic capacitor run android --livereload --external
```

The "--external" flag hosts the development server on all network interfaces (like adding --address=0.0.0.0) [[1]](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/capacitor-run#option-external). The "--livereload" flag can be shortened to "-l".

After executing the command, open your native IDE and run the app on the device or simulator. You will know that the livereload server is running when you see the message "Using app server http://x.x.x.x:8100" (your IP address).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ionic` cli for this:

```
ionic capacitor run android --livereload
```

For example.

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/capacitor-run

Comment: Ionic is not rebuilding the app to `www` or `android` folders. Thus, it is not updating it in the Android Studio and in the Android device. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: There may be something else going on if that's the case – does running the above command start the watch server?

Comment: Apparently, it is because in the browser it refreshes the page and updates the content. But the app continues with the old content. Should I enable any feature in the Android Studio? I can't find anything about it on the internet. Thanks for your help

Comment: However, if I stop the server and run `ng build` and then  restart the server with the command you mentioned, the app gets updated.

Comment: That's very strange! The above command should start the livereload server and point the compiled app to it so that the native side points to that.