# How to perform GET request as blob in Ionic 4 / Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to perform a GET request to download a PDF document to the phone. The `responseType` is `blob` as I need the result as a Blob file.

```
import {
  HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';

this.httpClient
   .get(specSheet.link, {
     responseType: 'blob'
   })
   .subscribe(result => {

     console.log('http client download result: ', result)
```

Everything works as expected on web and ran in Chrome. `http client download result:  Blob {size: 174016, type: "application/pdf"}`

But on iOS or Android the result is empty `http client download result: {}`.

What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: Here's a simple playground just downloading a test image:
https://github.com/davidseek/ionic-playground

It works perfectly fine ran on web. But not at all on a physical device. Web result is a Blob, phone result is empty: `{}`

Comment: allowMixedContent is set to true

Comment: Your request looks valid.

Comment: as an experiment, try to run

`this.httpClient.get('https://httpbin.org/image', {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    accept: 'image/*',
  }),
  responseType: 'blob'
}).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('Data', data);
});
`

Comment: this is how I've just verified blob request in iOS on my machine

Comment: Doesnt work for me. `Data {}`

Comment: I've used your exact code, ran on my iPhone X and Data is `{}`. On Chrome in web it's a valid blob.

Comment: This is weird I tried the code on this repo https://github.com/sneas/ionic-4-http-test `no-be` branch. Run simulator with `npm run ios` and switch to tab2. Got the expected result in the Safari console.

Comment: Creating an isolated playground project myself right now to check again. I'll be back in like 5mins.

Comment: I'm very happy to announce, that I have tried it with your code as well as mine in an isolated repo and it does NOT work. On my iPhone the `Data` log remains empty `{}`

Comment: https://github.com/davidseek/ionic-playground

Comment: does this `result` is supposed to be saved on file or stored? can I show it directly into a <img [src]="result"></img> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the console plugin not being able to display complex objects on the Xcode console.

If you debug the app using Safari remote inspector you'll see the actual blob. 
[image: blob]

Comment: Unbelievable. Yeah you helped me tremendously... Thank you! Since I got you here right now, do you have a little tip for me how I can deploy changes as fast as it gets from Visual Code -> Xcode -> iPhone? Right now I do: `ng build` -> `npx cap copy` -> switch to Xcode -> build. Is there like a faster way? Even with my iMac Pro this seems like a huge time waste.

Comment: you can use live reload, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53328647/ionic4-capacitor-android-livereload/53338145#53338145